# Trazer resultados de duas tabelas (erro INNER JOIN)

Tags: php, mysql, sql, banco-de-dados, phpmyadmin

Possuo a tabela secretarias com a seguinte estrutura:
[image: Tabela secretarias]

E a tabela trabalhador com a seguinte estrutura:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Relacionei a tabela trabalhador à tabela secretarias através da seguinte relação:
[image: Relação entre a tabela 'trabalhador' e a tabela 'secretarias']

Ou seja, estou relacionando a Foreign key id_secretaria da tabela 'trabalhador' à Primary Key id da tabela 'secretarias'.

Porem ao executar a seguinte query;

```
SELECT 
COUNT(trabalhador.id) AS qtdtrabalhadores, 
secretarias.id, 
secretarias.nome, 
secretarias.responsavel 
FROM trabalhador 
INNER JOIN secretarias 
ON trabalhador.id_secretaria = secretarias.id;
```

... recebo este erro:

> ## 1140 - In aggregated query without GROUP BY, expression #2 of SELECT list contains nonaggregated column 'cadastro-sumare.secretarias.id'; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

Alguém saberia me dizer o por quê? Agradeço desde já.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Explicando de uma forma simples, sempre que você utilizar uma função agregadora em seu SELECT (sum, max, count, min etc), você deve colocar todos campos do SELECT que não são agregados no GROUP BY. Dessa forma, você está dizendo ao banco de dados por quais campos você quer agrupar os resultados.

Sua query ficaria dessa forma:

```
SELECT 
COUNT(trabalhador.id) AS qtdtrabalhadores, 
secretarias.id, 
secretarias.nome, 
secretarias.responsavel 
FROM trabalhador 
INNER JOIN secretarias 
ON trabalhador.id_secretaria = secretarias.id
GROUP BY secretarias.id, 
secretarias.nome, 
secretarias.responsavel;
```

Comment: Perfeito, Bruno, deixou bem claro e simples, obrigado, viu? abrç!